# How to use "lt" and "gt" together to filter out wrong rows from DataFrame?

Tags: python, pandas

I have this code that filter out all values that are less than `lower_bound`:

```
s=df[col].lt(lower_bound)
if (len(s)>0):
    df1=df[~s].copy()
    if df1.empty:
        print("None")
    else:
        s1=df1.groupby(s.cumsum()).date_time.transform(lambda x : x.max()-x.min()).dt.seconds
        print(df1.loc[(s1>min_duration*60)])
else:
    print("None")
```

Now I want to add one more condition `s_u=df[col].gt(upper_bound)`.

If I add this line of code after `s=df[col].lt(lower_bound)`, then how should I update the block of `if (len(s)>0):` in order to avoid repeating the same code twice?

```
s_l=df[col].lt(lower_bound)
s_u=df[col].gt(upper_bound)
if (len(s_l)>0):
    df1=df[~s_l].copy()
    if df1.empty:
        print("None")
    else:
        s1=df1.groupby(s.cumsum()).date_time.transform(lambda x : x.max()-x.min()).dt.seconds
        print(df1.loc[(s1>min_duration*60)])
else:
    print("None")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my opinion simpliest is chain both conditions together by `&` for bitwise `AND` ot by `|` for bitwise `OR` and then use original solution:

```
s_l=df[col].lt(lower_bound)
s_u=df[col].gt(upper_bound)

s = s_l & s_u

if (len(s)>0):
    df1=df[~s].copy()
    if df1.empty:
        print("None")
    else:
        s1=df1.groupby(s.cumsum()).date_time.transform(lambda x : x.max()-x.min()).dt.seconds
        print(df1.loc[(s1>min_duration*60)])
else:
    print("None")
```

Comment: Do I understand correctly that if, for example, `s_u` is empty, it will not impact the code, right?

Comment: @Tatik - Not 100% sure, because hard test without data.